# Percent of polygon area within multiple ring buffers using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, overlay

I would like to calculate the percent of area of polygons that are within multiple ring buffers of a number of points. The polygons are associated with a specific point so I would like the buffers to extend out by specific intervals (5km, 10km, etc) up until it covers all the polygons associated with the point.

Then I would need to get the percent of cumulative areas of the polygons overlapping each interval extension of the buffer - e.g at 5km from point M1, percent of areas from the polygons (M1-P1, M1-P2 M1-P3, M1-P4,etc) is 10%, and at 10km, it is 40% and all the way up to 100% with the maximum buffer distance.
And this would be done on multiple points with other associated polygons (M2 with polygons M2-P1, M2-P2, M2-P3, etc).

A very rough illustration of the polygons, point and buffers are shown in the image below:

[image]

Can this be easily be done in ArcGIS Desktop?

I need the output from this to get into a cumulative distribution function.

Comment: In ArcGIS, yes, easily, add a field for original area and calculate geometry to populate the original area, intersect (limited to 2 feature classes in basic and standard license) the multiple ring buffer and the polygons, this should generate a complete polygon for each buffer - if your multiple ring buffer has overlaps. Add a new field to the intersected feature class for the percentage and calculate shape.area / original area (x 100 if you need it).

Comment: If you wish to ask about R and Python then please do that using separate questions.